# Belgium V Luxembourg - cost of living for a non-EU freelancer?

Tags: freelance-websites, legal, taxes, web-development

Any guides for the cost of living Belgium and Luxembourg for a non-EU IT freelancer/ self-employed? Eg, monthly rent, tax, VAT, health insurance, food, etc. Any local freelance websites for IT consultants?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Freelancing...

Comment: Belgium is way cheaper, Luxemburg is comparable to Switzerland. Every day there are traffic jams in the morning to come into the country and in the evening to get out of the country because you can make a much higher wage in Luxembuourg than Belgium, France of Germany and as long as you don't live in Luxemburg that can make a big difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not actually about freelancing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try [Expat Exchange](http://www.expatexchange.com/) they have guides on both countries you are looking at as well as tax information. If you are a US citizen or US Green Card holder, remember you have to file taxes to the US every year even if you do not live in the US. If you live outside of the US for around 330 days of the year you get an income exemption of around $100k that is non-taxable to the US but you still have to file. You can find others in their forum in the same situation, info on expenses, healthcare etc etc.